# How to set attribute value of child view attribute from parent xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have same kind of row value which are going to repeat in my activity multiple times so I have designed one row.xml for that and included required number of rows in my activity.xml by using include tag so if I want to change the value of the view which is there inside the row.xml file from activity.xml then how should we do that? I know that we can achieve this in Activity class and accessing it from activity but i want to deal this issue from xml only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have an identical row layout appearing `n` number of times, why not just use a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)?

Comment: Child have the edit text of different different input type also, those views also have some other views in between these views